# Is there a SSH proxy server

Tags: ssh, proxy

I'd like to have a static SSH endpoint on my static IP server that follows a device as it moves around.

---

I have a device that moves between IPs *and ports* a lot. When it moves, it "calls home" so I know what `IP:port` I can use to connect to it.

Unfortunately, using dynamic DNS doesn't work since the device changes ports.

Specifically, I'm using `ngrok` on my device. Yes, I am also paying them to get the equivalent of this but it would be nice to do this on my own servers. This problem also applies to other situations.

It would be pretty easy to first ssh into a static IP server and have a script that makes it easy to ssh into the roaming device: `ssh -p $roamingPort user@$roamingIp`. Or alternatively, make a similar script to run on client devices that asks the static IP server where the roaming device currently is and then SSH's to the roaming device directly.

This would be relatively easy for HTTP with current tools. For instance using nginx to proxy requests to a different URL.

But none of that gives the "nice user experience" of some static SSH endpoint that follows the roaming device around, that can be used with many ssh clients.

I've been looking for a way to do this and have come up empty handed.

Whatever solution to this should also take care of `known_hosts` nicely.

This is slightly related to [Hookable SSH proxy server to direct connection to remote host](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42499850/hookable-ssh-proxy-server-to-direct-connection-to-remote-host) but I'd like to run that service on a box I control.

---

EDIT: The following works once and not again until it is manually restarted. It also never closes on its own.

`mkfifo fifo && nc -l -p $staticPort < fifo | nc $roamingIP $roamingPort > fifo`

Comment: Why are you changing the ssh port?

Comment: @nbari I'm not, ngrok does that

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like [saltstack](https://saltstack.com/), This may be probably too much for what you want, but is very useful especially when having dynamic clients/nodes that change random and you just need to access to them through a known host:port, normally used for load balancing for example.

This implies you will need a server (salt master) and your nodes (clients/instances/devices).

In your case, you could use HAproxy in one fixed static IP/port server that will update automatically the backends by using [salt mines](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/topics/mine/).

An example of this can be found here: https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/topics/mine/#example